# Cache block swap between different ways

Tags: gem5

I am trying to achieve a kind of functionality in cache which will swap the blocks within the same set but different ways. For example, data stored in way 0 will be moved to way 1 and the data was stored in way 1 then is moved to way 0. The block should not be evicted from the cache during this swapping.

The cache model is the classic set-associative cache (not Ruby).

I noticed `cache_blk.hh` tells what kind of data is stored in a cache block, so I wrote something in base_tag as below to perform the content swapping.

```
blkA->tag=blkB->tag;
blkA->srcMasterId=blkB->srcMasterId
blkA->task_id=blkB->task_id
blkA->tickInserted=blkB->tickInserted
blkA->refCount=blkB->refCount
blkA->whenReady=blkB->whenReady
blkA->status=blkB->status
for (int i=0;i<blk_size;i++)
{
   *(blkA->data + i)=*(blkB->data + i);
}
```

This modification caused data corruption, so it did not work correctly. Can someone give me some suggestions about this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you are not handling coherence. You have to make sure that the blocks are neither in the MSHR nor in the writebuffer; and they must both be readable and writable.

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply! I did think it could be an MSHR coherence issue but from my understanding about MSHR (please do point out if I am wrong), it only stores the currently missing data. If the data is already in the cache (let's say the blks A and B I mentioned in my question are stored in the L2 cache), non of blks A and B should exist in MSHR since they have already been fetched into L2, therefore, I assume this data swapping will only happen internally in L2 cache? I haven't thought about the writebuffer, I will think about it later. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: The MSHR can hold blocks that are missing coherence bits. For example, if you have a write to a block that is only readable, it goes into the MSHR. See handleTimingReqMiss().

Comment: @DanielCarvalho Thanks for your suggestions! I will have a look at that function.